# find every item and the most expensive with some condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following relations and

1.I want to find the pids of parts supplied by every supplier and at less than 200.
(If any supplier either does not simply the part or charges more than 200 for it, the part is not selected)

The fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b5d4

```
Supplies            
sid     1   2   3   4   5
sname   Jason   David   John    Peter   Jay
address 221 2b  3c  4d  5e


Parts                       
pid     10  20  30  40  50  60
pname   Head    Body    Hand    Leg Arm Foot
color   red blue    green   white   red green


Catalog             
sid     1   1   2   2   3   4   1   1   4   4   1   5   5   3   3   2
pid     10  20  20  30  30  40  30  40  10  50  50  50  10  60  10  10
cost    150 220 150 150 130 125 130 280 123 126 120 100 100 210 100 50
```

So I do the following query
I think that it equal that `there is no parts that the suppliers don't supply it.`

```
SELECT C.pid
FROM CATALOG C
WHERE C.cost < 200
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT S.sid
                  FROM Suppliers S
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS
                  (SELECT P.pid
                   FROM Parts P
                   WHERE P.pid = C.pid
                   AND S.sid = C.sid ))
```

but it return null, it should return 10.

2.I want to find for every supplier that supplies a green part and a red part, print the name and price of the most expensive part that she supplies.

I just can find out the green and red part but cannot find the most expensive.

The query is that I have tried.

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Suppliers AS S,
     Parts AS P1,
     CATALOG AS C1,
     Parts AS P2 ,
     CATALOG AS C2
WHERE S.sid = C1.sid
  AND C1.pid = P1.pid
  AND S.sid = C2.sid
  AND C2.pid = P2.pid
  AND ( P1.color = 'red'
       AND P2.color = 'green' )
```

How do I fix it? Thank in advance.

ps Sorry that I have to go to class and I will reply about 6 hours later.

Comment: Could you please clarify why `10` should be in results list in part 1?

Comment: Because the part that pid is 10 appears in each suppliers and all are less than 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PART1

Select pid from catalog where cost<200 group by pid having count(Sid)>=(SelecT Count(sid) from Suppliers)

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b5d4/81)

Part2-:

```
  Select t.sname,Max(Catalog.cost) from (SELECT  S.sname,c2.cost,c2.sid
FROM Suppliers AS S, Parts AS P1, Catalog AS C1, Parts AS P2 , Catalog AS C2
WHERE S.sid = C1.sid
AND C1.pid = P1.pid
AND S.sid = C2.sid
AND C2.pid = P2.pid
AND (
P1.color =  'red'
AND P2.color =  'green'
) ) t inner join Catalog on t.sid =Catalog.sid
group by t.sid
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b5d4/88)

Answer (score 1):

For part 1, I think this query is more readable and returns you your expected result:

```
SELECT a.pid
FROM
(
    SELECT pid, MAX(cost) max_price, COUNT(1) amount 
    FROM Catalog 
    GROUP BY pid
) a
WHERE
    a.amount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Suppliers)
    AND max_price < 200
```

Now opposite to what you wrote, here is where you need the `EXISTS` to check for supplier having either red or green part:

```
SELECT 
    sid
FROM
    Suppliers
WHERE
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM
            Catalog
            LEFT JOIN Parts ON Catalog.pid = Parts.pid
        WHERE
            Catalog.sid = Suppliers.sid
            AND Parts.color = 'green'
    )
    AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM
            Catalog
            LEFT JOIN Parts ON Catalog.pid = Parts.pid
        WHERE
            Catalog.sid = Suppliers.sid
            AND Parts.color = 'red'
    )
```

And finally, the full result should look like:

```
SELECT 
    sid,
    (
        SELECT pname
        FROM 
            Catalog
            LEFT JOIN Parts ON Catalog.pid = Parts.pid
        WHERE
            Catalog.sid = Suppliers.sid
            AND Catalog.cost = (SELECT MAX(c.cost) FROM Catalog c WHERE c.sid = Suppliers.sid)
        LIMIT 1
    ) name,
    (
        SELECT cost
        FROM 
            Catalog
            LEFT JOIN Parts ON Catalog.pid = Parts.pid
        WHERE
            Catalog.sid = Suppliers.sid
            AND Catalog.cost = (SELECT MAX(c.cost) FROM Catalog c WHERE c.sid = Suppliers.sid)
        LIMIT 1
    ) cost
FROM
    Suppliers
WHERE
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM
            Catalog
            LEFT JOIN Parts ON Catalog.pid = Parts.pid
        WHERE
            Catalog.sid = Suppliers.sid
            AND Parts.color = 'green'
    )
    AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM
            Catalog
            LEFT JOIN Parts ON Catalog.pid = Parts.pid
        WHERE
            Catalog.sid = Suppliers.sid
            AND Parts.color = 'red'
    )
```

[SQL fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b5d4/65)

Comment: No, I am not following your query logic, I'm afraid :)

Answer (score 1):

For th part 2 you can try

```
    Select S.Sname,P.pname,c.cost  from Suppliers As S, Parts AS P, Catalog AS C
    where S.sid=C.Sid And P.pid     =C.pid     
    And color    in ('green','red')
        And c.cost in 
            (Select max(cost) from Catalog AS C1,Parts AS P1 where c1.pid=P1.pid and P1.color=P.color)
```

Comment: `color in ('green','red')` is not the same as (pseudocode) `color in each of ('green', 'red')`

Comment: Select S.Sname,P.pname,c.cost  from Suppliers As S, Parts AS P, Catalog AS C
  where S.sid=C.Sid And P.pid     =C.pid     
  And color    in ('green','red')
   And c.cost in 
    (Select max(cost) from Catalog AS C1,Parts AS P1 where c1.pid=P1.pid and P1.color in  ('green','red'))